# Удаление или скрытие элемента svg на сайте посредством javascript

Tags: javascript, svg

[image: Вот такой назойливый объект, который я ни как не могу удалить]

пробывал делать вот так, не получается

```
"document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0].style.display='none';"
```

и вот так тоже не хочет

```
"while(paras3[0]) { paras3[0].parentNode.removeChild(paras3[0]);}" +
        "var paras4 = document.getElementsByTagName('svg');" +
```

через имя класса тоже не получается…

Есть у кого нибудь идеи?

Answer (score 1):

Где вы пишете `"document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0].style.display='none';`?. Вот так, например, вполне работает:

```
<svg>...ваш html-код</svg>

<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0].style.display='none';
</script>
```

Comment: Пишу клиент для сайта под андроид, загружаю в webview скрипт, и почему то данный вариант не работает...Точнее работает, но через раз..

Comment: Хорошо бы посмотреть код страницы целиком, если это возможно.

Comment: [ссылка](http://www.tui.ru/)

Comment: По ссылке я не нашел код вида document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0].style.display='none'. Хотелось бы посмотреть, как и где он вызывается.

Comment: я же написал,Пишу клиент для сайта под андроид, данный код пишу через webview. load url

Comment: Может ваш код срабатывает до того как загрузиться svg?